# How to build a gadget that retrieves quotes from google

Tags: c#, google-finance-api

I'd like to build a windows gadget that shows

1. the main indexes such as dow, nasaq...
2. and my portfolio stocks like msft appl...

I want this to represent real time(or at least 15min delay)

I found a project that gets the summary of a quote here:

https://code.google.com/p/googlefinance/downloads/list

But I don't know if this api gives an online(/delayed) quotes.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the API gives you delayed prices, you normally have to pay a subscription fee to get the live proces.

Comment: Correct. You always get delayed prices and you have to pay (usually a lot) for real-time